# Eclipse remove name patterns in File search

Tags: eclipse, history

Where does Eclipse save the recent patterns in the "File name Patterns" by File Search. I want to delete some of these entries, but couldn't find them in any text/temp file.

Many thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open the file `<Your eclipse workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.search/dialog_settings.xml`

Check all the child nodes of `<section name="EXTENSIONS">` tag and change the values and restart eclipse.

Comment: Maybe it is obvious, but I was making this mistake. First close Eclipse, then edit the file. Otherwise, your changes will be overwritten when you close it.

Answer (score 1):

The search dialog settings are saved in a `dialog_settings.xml` file in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.search` directory.

The text search page uses the `<section name="TextSearchPage">` part of this file.

Note: On Unix, Linux and Mac systems directories starting with `.` are hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this directory does not exist in my workspace. I could only find a dialog_settings.xml file under org.eclipse.ui.workbench plugin, which is almost empty. Just one note, we are using IBM - Rational Application Developer.

Comment: Does this File Search appear as a tab on a Search dialog along with other types of search or somewhere else?

Comment: yes, standard eclipse search dialog along with Java search, Link search etc. (I can not paste an image here)

Comment: I suppose IBM may have replaced the standard page. Note that the dialog_settings.xml file is not saved until you exit from Eclipse and the workspace is saved. Alt+Shift+F1 with the page selected should show details about the page.

Comment: I have no idea. Alt+Shift+F1 shows me: The contributing plug-in:
org.eclipse.search (3.6.1.r363_v20120227)